# Nginx RTMP module to generate HLS

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, hlsl, opus

I'm streaming an audio stream with opus codec from Kurento
via ffmpeg to nginx-rtmp-module. I'm using the below command to stream to nginx-rtmp:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp  -i test-audio.sdp  
-c:a libopus  -f opus rtmp://<server_ip>/live/<stream_name>
```

I see no error on the ffmpeg side. But there's no m3u8 file being generated. But I noticed the following in the nginx log:

```
2020/11/23 23:19:31 [info] 95#0: *8 connect: app='live' args='' flashver='FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf57.83' swf_url='' tc_url='rtmp://192.168.4.28:1935/live' page_url='' acodecs=0 vcodecs=0 object_encoding=0, client: 172.17.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:1935
```

Noticed the `acodes=0`. Does this mean that it doesn't like opus codec?

Below is my nginx.conf:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        application hopefm {
            live on;
            interleave on;

            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It doesn't detect any codecs, video or audio. Are you sure your ffmpeg command is producing some output?

Answer (score 1):

Found out why it is not working. The correct command should be

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp  -i test-audio.sdp  
-c:a aac  -f flv rtmp://<server_ip>/live/<stream_name>
```

I was missing the `-f flv` and also flash doesn't like opus either, I needed to specify `aac` instead.